# Unable to create a Kafka sink - Python - Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, amazon-eks

Currently I'm working with EKS/Kubernetes cluster and I installed Apache kafka as a service.

Internally in the cluster I can do all the kafka operations such as create, delete, consume or read topics with commands like:

```bash
#List topics
kubectl exec -it <My pod> -- kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server kafka.<My namespace>.svc.cluster.local:9092

#Create topic
kubectl exec -it <My pod> -- kafka-topics.sh --create --topic test --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1 --bootstrap-server kafka.<My namespace>.svc.cluster.local:9092

#Delete topic
kubectl exec -it <My pod> -- kafka-topics.sh --delete --topic test --bootstrap-server kafka.<My namespace>.svc.cluster.local:9092

#Produce
kubectl exec -it <My pod> -- kafka-console-producer.sh --topic test --bootstrap-server kafka.<My namespace>.svc.cluster.local:9092 < value.json

#Consume
kubectl exec -it <My pod> -- kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic test --from-beginning --bootstrap-server kafka.<My namespace>.svc.cluster.local:9092
```

Now I want, with a lambda or some python code to ingest data without entering to the cluster, as

```py
from confluent_kafka.admin import AdminClient, NewTopic
def list_kafka_topics(bootstrap_servers):
    admin_client = AdminClient({'bootstrap.servers': bootstrap_servers})
    
    topics = admin_client.list_topics().topics
    topic_names = list(topics.keys())
    
    return topic_names

bootstrap_servers = 'BOOTSTRAPS'

topics = list_kafka_topics(bootstrap_servers)
print("Lista de Topics en Kafka:")
for topic in topics:
    print(topic)
```

The error that always appears is:

```
Failed to resolve 'kafka:9092': No such host is known.  (after 2703ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
```

can someone help me in order to ingest data to a kafka cluster already installed in EKS? Or to thing about a new strategy always with the purpose of ingesting data.

Comment: Lambda knows nothing about k8s services for pods. You'll need a load balancer address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your Kafka service is running inside pods.

To access a Kubernetes pods i.e service from outside the cluster, you would typically expose the Service to the external world by using a Kubernetes `Ingress` or `LoadBalancer`. This allows external traffic to reach your service.

Then use the ingress endpoint inside your Lambda.